# EN61000-4-5 Surge protection of PCB power supply

Tags: power-supply, emc, emi-filtering, tvs, surge-protection

I am trying to better understand how EMC testing is simulated and passed. The datasheet of the CQB50W12-72S12 says it pass level 4 line to earth 4kV; and +- line to line 2kV with just a TVS diode (SMDJ180A) and 82uF capacitor (UCS2E820MHD1TN).

After downloading the littelfuse TVS diode spice model (https://www.littelfuse.com/technical-resources/spice-models.aspx) and simulating a simple 8/20us pulse test I figured the voltage would clamp a bit closer to the 200V max rating of the power supply but it peaks at about 1kV.

It doesn't seem that the TVS diode is going to save the power supply referencing the simulation. I must not be doing the simulation correctly or understanding something about how ltspice works. Or maybe there is more to the power supply internally.

Is there a better way to simulate this for a higher degree of confidence before verifying with real components?

Link to tvs datasheet: https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=2d9772b3-822b-4362-914d-b74e0a706638&filename=littelfuse-tvs-diode-smdj-datasheet

.model description downloaded from littelfuse (I know it says 170 in simulation but there was no 180 tvs in downloaded .txt):
[image]

Simulation:
[image]

Comment: The first rule is get the number of the document correct. It should be EN61000-4-5 and not what you wrote in the title.

Comment: Please link the data sheet of the TVS and put the simulation model into your question.

Comment: pasted link to datasheet and posted pic of .subckt info which can be downloaded from link to littelfuse resources @andyaka

Comment: I'm no expert but I believe the parameter RS may be waaaay too high. Try and find a more reliable model. Also, it's worth shorting out R6 because lightning surges like these are relative to hard earth.

Comment: RS seems fine, given that these models appear tuned for breakdown only. (The forward voltage drop will be wildly higher than actual due to the same RS.) Note that breakdown is ~200V but Vp is 350V at ~50A, or 150V/50A = 3 ohms ballpark internal resistance.

Comment: Note that line-line mains surge is done with a 2-ohm generator, and line-ground is done with more (12Ω, see IEC 61000-4-5:2014 Fig.6; note it's also a "combined wave generator", the waveform depends on load resistance). For simulation purposes, grounding simply needs to be assigned *somewhere*, and grounding one line as here is fine; the large value resistor doesn't matter (it is *technically* better without).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, in your other post, EN50121-3-2 is mentioned, which uses a **42Ω** surge condition instead.  This is *far less strenuous*, and in fact right within ratings of the diode (~50A peak; though it is a 1.2/50 not 8/20µs waveform in this condition).  The capacitor will also have a significant contribution (42Ω * 82µF = 3.4ms time constant), and its ESR will have less voltage drop at this lower peak current.